# hibernate ormtype that maps as a tinyint in Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, orm, coldfusion, hibernate-mapping

What `ormtype` in ColdFusion 2016 Hibernate maps to tinyint in Microsoft SQL?

```
property name="varName" ormtype="boolean" default="0";
```

The above worked in ColdFusion 9 but we've upgraded to ColdFusion 2016 and this is no longer the case.

Comment: You mention ColdFusion 11 and also tagged it as such but then you say you upgraded to 2016. Which version is it? That might matter.

Comment: Yes, it might.  Server Product ColdFusion 2016
Version 2016.0.0.298074
Tomcat Version 8.0.27.0

Comment: Since tinyint has a range of 0-255, I am not sure why it would map to "boolean". Have you tried "tinyint" or "short"?